# Assembly Game character movement slowing down my game

Tags: assembly, x86

I am making a game in assembly with the game being a character object (in this case it is the 'X' char) moves to dodge falling 0's and 1's. My falling objects are perfect the only problem I'm having is that if someone were to hold down a direction either left or right my falling objects stop to accommodate the player object's new position. I'm using the irvine library for procs such as readkey which gets keyboard input just about everything else is 100% me. I'm not sure why it stops everything to complete a line of code that is only executed on the first go through on a print cycle. Any help would be much appreciated. Below I'll post the code. For right now it runs on an infinite loop which is broken if you get hit by an object.

```
 ;******* proc to make it easier to reprint the rain;Kilian Proc

print PROC 


    mov esi,0
    mov count, 0; intilize as zero to reset the print proc

PrintAll: 




      mov ecx, count
    mov ebx , 0
    cmp esi,4
    je four
    jmp end4

four:
  mov esi , 4
end4:

inLoop2:

    mov dl,xArray[ebx]

    mov dh,yArray[ebx]
    call Gotoxy            ;Moves cursor to the position of rain


    mov al,rainArray[ebx]
    call WriteChar          ;Rewrite rain

    push ecx
    cmp ebx, 0
    je xmov
    jmp endx
xmov:
    call ReadKey          ; looks for keyboard input
     call RightIf
      call LeftIf
endx:   
    pop ecx
    call fall

    cmp ecx, 0
    jne decrease
    jmp endD
decrease:
    dec ecx
endD:
    inc ebx





    cmp ebx, esi
    ja endinLoop
    jmp inLoop2

endinLoop:

    mov eax , 105
    call delay
    call clrscr

    mov dh,23d              ;move cursor to character's current position ********* Added to this version by Killian edited by John
    mov dl , beginX
    call Gotoxy
    mov al,'X'              ;move X into al                               *********
    call WriteChar          ;print it                   **********
    call Crlf
    xor al,al               ;clear


    cmp ecx, 0
    je  random
    mov ebx, 0
    jmp inLoop2
random:

    mov eax, 5
    call RandomRange
    mov ebx, eax

    cmp ebx , 0
    je Increase
    jmp PrintAll


Increase:
    cmp esi, 4
    je PrintAll
    inc count
    inc esi 
    jmp PrintAll
EndPrint:

    ret
print       ENDP
```

This part of the code is doing all the heavy lifting the problem is in here somewhere. If you would like to see the full code you can go here [Git Repo](https://github.com/Jkkarr2015/AssemblyMatrixRain/)

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the issue love this community ;D

Comment: If you found your solution, please post it as the answer so that others can find it too :)

Comment: To fix this problem I moved the calls to ReadKey, RightIf, and LeftIf down under the area where I print the 'X' again. It fixed the problem pretty good.I'll put the code below.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was putting the calls to ReadKey, RightIf, and LeftIf down under where I print the 'X' again code below:

```
 endinLoop:

    mov eax , 105
    call delay
    call clrscr

    mov dh,23d              ;move cursor to character's current position ********* Added to this version by Killian edited by John
    mov dl , beginX
    call Gotoxy
    mov al,'X'              ;move X into al                              *********
    call WriteChar          ;print it                   **********
    call Crlf
    xor al,al               ;clear

    push ecx
    call ReadKey
    call Rightif
    call Leftif
    pop ecx

    cmp ecx, 0
    je  random
    mov ebx, 0
    jmp inLoop2
random:
```

Comment: I had to push ecx because I found out that my Rightif and Leftif area changed it's value and I needed to save what it was.